# Trying to Programmatically Create & Open a new Outlook Email

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

I have a winforms application and I am trying to create a method that will create and open a new Outlook Email.  So far I have

```
private void CreateOutlookEmail()
    {
        try
        {                
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)
                this.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.Subject = "This is the subject";
            mailItem.To = "someone@example.com";
            mailItem.Body = "This is the message.";
            mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
            mailItem.Display(false);
        }
        catch (Exception eX)
        {
            throw new Exception("cDocument: Error occurred trying to Create an Outlook Email"
                                + Environment.NewLine + eX.Message);
        }
    }
```

But the 'CreateItem' reference is underlined with the error message

"does not contain a definition for CreateItem"

I thought 'CreateItem' was a standard method for MS Office items, but admittedly I did find the above code on another website and simply copied it.

What am I misunderstanding please?

Comment: Where are you placing this method? I.e. does the reference to `this` reside in a VSTO Outlook addin project? I suspect you need to create a new Outlook addin project, and then place this code in that project.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Think about it. You are calling the `CreateItem` method on `this` current object. Have you defined the `CreateItem` method in this class?

Instead of your:

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem) this.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

You need the lines:

```
Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem) outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

You create an instance of the outlook application, on which you can call the `CreateItem` method.

### Edit

There are two more things to make this work properly.

1) Add a reference to the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` package to your project

2) Ensure you have the appropriate using statement in your class

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

Comment: I have suggested this edit to the MSDN page where you may have copied your code from.

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
string subject = "My subject";
string emailTag = string.Format("mailto:someone@test.com?subject={0}", subject);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(emailTag);
```

Comment: Hi this works a treat on my Local PC but i'm assuming this needs an Office application / Instance running on the server to work as it won't open Outlook 2007 when running from a remote server based website. Am I correct or is there something I need to do to get it to work on a Live website, like reference it in my WebConfig, etc.? thanks

Comment: Never use Office Interop on a remote server.  Per Microsoft ( https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office ): "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."

Answer (score 6):

In my experience Office.Interop can be troublesome and simply kicking off Outlook with the appropriate arguments may represent a simpler and more portable option:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\OUTLOOK.EXE", "/c ipm.note /m name@address.com"));
```

Outlook command line switches give you many more options with numerous sources of info (try http://www.outlook-tips.net/how-to/using-outlook-command-lines)

Comment: There's a reason, as I recently discovered in my own winforms app, that this is a bad idea: It turns out there's a limit, character based, on how much you can put into the body of the email when you do it this way. Interop, from the standpoint of the Winforms world, is actually the smoothest way to do it.