# Error: 'MyProject.Email does not contain a definition for 'Application'

Tags: c#, email, .net-4.0

'Dashboard.Email' does not contain a definition for 'Application' and no extension method 'Application' accepting a first argument of type 'Dashboard.Email' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've tried adding references and using statements to no avail. I'm just trying to create a simple mail object in VS2010 .NET 4 Framework.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Deployment.Application;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace Dashboard
{
    public class Email
    {
        public void CreateEmailItem()
       {
           MailItem eMail = (MailItem)this.Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

            eMail.Subject = "This is the subject";
            eMail.To = "example@gmail.com";
            eMail.Body = "This is the body";
            eMail.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceLow;

            ((_MailItem)eMail).Send();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can refer this link for the answer


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242745/trying-to-programmatically-create-open-a-new-outlook-email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this here is refers to the current class which is Email class. It does not define Application property defined. Hence the error.

Looks like you are trying to create MailItem using Outlook interop.

Replace

```
MailItem eMail = (MailItem)this.Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

with

```
MailItem eMail = (MailItem)Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

Your code otherwise looks fine to me but **Codesnippet at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb644320%28v=office.14%29.aspx article on MSDN might give you a good idea.**