# Programatically create & send outlook email WITH a visual email popping up on screen

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, add-in

I want to be emailing with a Outlook add-in, I've followed as a previous user did:

[Trying to Programmatically Create & Open a new Outlook Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242745/trying-to-programmatically-create-open-a-new-outlook-email)

To create said email, but What if anything can I do to make it so outlook doesn't have this email pop-up on screen, and just sends it.

`MailItem` doesnt seem to have any kind of `.Visible` attribute that I'm aware of.

Is there a way to "hide" the Email? My add-in is set to a timer so it's sort of annoying for my system to pop up an email window on me every 30 minutes :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you don't want to display the email, don't call `Display`. Call `Send` instead.

Comment: even if I'm calling .Display(false); it appears though... I'd have assumed that'd STOP it from displaying

Comment: Don't call `Display` at all. You don't want to display it, so why would you call `Display`? The parameter just indicates whether the window you will see is modal or not.

Comment: Fair enough. If it'll assume not to desplay with out that instruction I'm all for it. Thanks